Не корректная работа клавиатуры ноутбука
Возникла проблема с клавиатурой ноутбука. Во время игры в один момент перестали работать некоторые клавиши (Esc, 2) без взаимодействия с другими клавишами. При этом они спокойно работают как обычно, если вместе с ними нажать любую кнопку (кроме Alt и Win). Также же продолжают работать комбинации по типу Alt+Esc (переход между окнами), Shift+2 (", @).
Данные кнопки работают как обычно, если ноутбук какое-то время (от ~30 мин) был выключен, после работы в нем, даже в сидя в браузере, данные кнопки начинают реагировать только при комбинации. То же самое касается биоса. Если сразу в биос зайти без предварительной работы в нем, то работают как надо, но если через какое-то время после работы сразу, то только комбинация
В интернете не нашел так такового ответа в чем дело, как и собственно такой проблемы у кого либо еще.
Если кто знает в чем может быть проблема и пути решения, то был бы благодарен, тк клавиатура специфичная и стоит от 5к руб.

Если есть подозрения на некорректную работу ноутбука, то лучше рассмотреть вариант с переустановкой ОС. Если есть подозрения на механические повреждения или если переустановка ОС не помогла, то лучше отнести ноутбук в сервис для замены клавиатуры.

До загрузки ноута зайдите в биос (или загружите любой образ с флешки). Там Esc работает правильно? Или так же как в ОС компьютера?

@StanislavVolodarskiy забыл уточнить,  но сейчас вам тут отвечу, и допишу в вопросе это. Данные кнопки работают как обычно, если ноутбук какое-то время (от ~30 мин) был выключен, после работы в нем, даже в сидя в браузере, данные кнопки начинают реагировать только при комбинации. То же самое касается биоса. Если сразу в биос зайти без предварительной работы в нем, то работают как надо, но если через какое-то время после работы сразу, то только комбинация

Можно принять что это не софт. Или что-то внутри перегрелось, отпаялось или треснуло и теперь, после нагрева, глючит или пропадает контакт. Тут ничего не посоветую. Или у вас плохо зафиксирован шлейф клавиатуры в ЗИФе (разъеме) и тоже при нагреве контакт теряет. Выньте, вставьте заново, только посмотрите как с ЗИФом обращаться. Это вы сами сможете. А вообще в сервис надо, где не по фотографии лечат а чинят нормально.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Да, скорее всего от перегрева, тк сейчас как раз произвел андервольтинг, после чего при достижении температуры +- 77 на процессоре перестают работать данные клавиши. Спасибо, что помогли разобраться!
